# CLion on Macintosh

Tags: c++, c, macos, clion

Has anyone been able to get this working? The [best resource I could find instructs you to revamp the CmakeList.txt as indicated](http://raycast.net/2014/10/19/clion-multiple-binaries.html). However I still can't compile anything with it. Repeated error "2"s and sym_cal warnings. It's supposed to handle GCC/Clang compilers, and from what I understand clang is built in to Mac.

This software is in a testing phase (EAP they call it) so I guess it's more prone to compiler warnings than others.

Comment: Can you show the specific errors/warnings you get? I'm usually pretty good at this kind of porting, but I don't really want to have to DL the project myself.

Comment: "/Applications/CLion EAP.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake" --build /Users/Joe/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/ae20c1e2/ae20c1e2/Debug --target Ctesting -- -j 8
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (set):
  Syntax error in cmake code at
 /Users/Joe/gDrive/Cylon/C:C++/Ctesting/CMakeLists.txt:4
  when parsing string
 ${Users/Joe/gDrive/Cylon/C:C++/Ctesting}/build/
  syntax error, unexpected cal_SYMBOL, expecting } (41)
See also "/Users/Joe/Library/Caches/clion10/cmake/generated/ae20c1e2/ae20c1e2/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

Comment: And what does that CMakeLists.txt file contain? It looks like you have a syntax error.

Comment: I copied the entire code from the link given above, and replaced the generic directory with my real one.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the colon in the path ?